# Cannot set colors resource for Color Preference picker Android

Tags: android, android-resources, color-picker

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am need to create color picker. Beautiful color picker. So I am using this picker - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4401. What I am doing is simple, open color picker on click listener of a button. But throwing error when I click button.

This is how code to open picker in activity

```
private void openCaptionTfColorPicker()
    {
        new ColorDialog.Builder(this)
                .setColorShape(ColorShape.CIRCLE) //CIRCLE or SQUARE
                .setColorChoices(R.array.color_choices) //an array of colors
                .setSelectedColor(Color.GREEN) //the checked color
                .setTag(TAG_TF_COLOR_PICKER) // tags can be useful when multiple components use the picker within an activity
                .show();
    }
```

My activity implements ColorDialog.OnColorSelectedListener

This is my color_choices array in arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="color_choices">
        <item>@android:color/black</item>
        <item>@android:color/white</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This is error in logcat when I click button

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                               Process: memegenerator.waiyanhein.com.memegenerator, PID: 17860
>                                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                   at
>   memegenerator.waiyanhein.com.adapter.InstalledTemplatesAdapter.getItemCount(InstalledTemplatesAdapter.java:92)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:2938)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2904)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

What I can think is, something is wrong with my color resource array. Why does this error get thrown?

Comment: try to create array in colors.xml file.. same as given in example (https://github.com/kizitonwose/colorpreference/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/colors.xml_

Comment: It could be because you're using a `<string-array/>` for color resources. Try using `<integer-array/>` or just `<array/>`.

Comment: Link is dead @Mehta

Comment: I tried both. Not working @SlashG

Comment: @WaiYanHein: updated link https://github.com/kizitonwose/colorpreference/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: Yeah. I got it working now. Thank you.